# Space After New Lines in RichTextBox 

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, line, space

A RichTextBox puts extra space between lines when a user presses enter or inserts text, and that's what I'm trying to get away from. I searched around and the only decent solution I found is this one:

```
Setter SetParagraphMargin = new Setter();
SetParagraphMargin.Property = Paragraph.MarginProperty;
SetParagraphMargin.Value = new Thickness(0);

Style style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(Paragraph);
style.Setters.Add(SetParagraphMargin);

rtb.Resources.Add("Style", style);
```

But this still doesn't work. Does anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem, and i solved it by modifying the Xaml of the RichTextBox:

```xml
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Don't know how that's different than setting the style manually like you did, but for me it worked.

**Update**: To change it in code, you need to use the target type as key:

```
Style noSpaceStyle = new Style(typeof(Paragraph));
noSpaceStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
rtb.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
```

Comment: sorry.. i didnt mention that i need to do it in the code and not in xaml. but your solution would work fine!

Comment: Ok, found the problem. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with property thickness

```
 my_paragraph.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0);
```