# How do I eliminate the space placed between paragraphs in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I eliminate the space placed between paragraphs in a RichTextBox?

```
gobjParagaph.Inlines.Add(new Run(st));
gobjFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(gobjParagaph);
gRTbx.Document = gobjFlowDoc;
```

After displaying information in a RichTextBox programmatically, the customer edits the information.  However, when the customer hits "Enter" button, the cursor jumps down two spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I found this works too:

```
 <RichTextBox.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
   </Style>
 </RichTextBox.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the line height:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();    
Paragraph p = rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;    
p.LineHeight = 10;
```

Source: [Space After New Lines in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897582/)